Find the partition separator for a given Linux block device
I'm writing a script that will partition several disks on a Linux system. These disks can be all sorts of block devices. I need to find a way to reliably create the names of the partitions that will be created before I have created them. In other words, I need to know the character or string that will separate the disk's device name from the partition number when the partitions have been created.
Is there a file in the /sys/block tree that I can find from the root devices' node that contains this information?
I currently check if the root device' name contains nvme or mmcblk, in which case I use p as the separator. Otherwise I use the empty string.
But this seems fragile and likely incomplete.

To directly answer your question, the code for assigning the device name for a partition is in the Linux kernel, in add_partition in block/partitions/core.c: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/88fac17500f4ea49c7bac136cf1b27e7b9980075/block/partitions/core.c#L330
if (isdigit(dname[strlen(dname) - 1]))
    dev_set_name(pdev, "%sp%d", dname, partno);
else
    dev_set_name(pdev, "%s%d", dname, partno);

It's pretty simple.  If the base device ends in a digit, there's a "p" between it and the partition index.  Otherwise, there's no "p".
As an alternative to this approach, consider instead writing a udev rule that would create an entry in /dev/disk/by-uuid or by-id.  This would give you something you can explicitly look up once the new partition device entry pops up.

Perfect. udev rule doesn't work for the situation this is in, but the logic is very simple (and, well, logical). So I can easily replicate that where I need it. Thank you very much!
